# Unity Activate Trigger is not Triggering

Tags: triggers, unity-game-engine

For some reason a simple trigger using the standard ActivateTrigger script is not working.

I've got a box which is marked Is Trigger and has the Activate Trigger script component. It is supposed to turn on (activate) a point light in this "room", called Point light 1.

As seen from the image below, everything looks like it should be set up correctly. Yet when the player controller hits the box, the light is not activated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because your Component Box Collider is disable.
Just Click on the checkbox near Box Collider name.